# How to load a XML from a 3rd party site with Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am trying to load a 3rd party xml document using JQuery/Javascript, but without success:

```
alert("Before");
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
            alert("OK");
    }
});
alert("After");
```

The "OK" box is not displayed, but the xml is available with a browser. This code example is available at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gv9Kr/).

How is one supposed to load a 3rd party XML in Javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading cross domain html page with jQuery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Also, you need the protocol for the url (http://)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protocol has to be specified, `http://` (or perhaps `https://`).

```
url: "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml",
```

Updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/gv9Kr/1/

As you can see, the code does not work, because of the Same-origin policy.

Comment: It still does not work with 'http'. I guess I should have this xml on my own website.

Comment: @JVerstry You have a few options: 1) A server-side proxy, 2) Another data-exchanging format, such as JSONP (if it's supported by the server).

Comment: @JVerstry I just looked for you, there's no JSONP existing support for the service. You have to use a custom server-side proxy.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, I fiddled a solution with a PHP file loading the xml. My javascript code loads the php file from my site.

Answer (score 2):

It is due to cross domain restrictions. There are plenty of resources available in the internet just google on it. There are various work arounds to it one of which is **[YQL](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-yql-and-jquery/)**

Answer (score 1):

[same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents you from doing that. you must find ways to circumvent this. for JSON type data, there is [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/). here's a [question from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829223/make-a-cross-domain-request-for-xml-from-a-local-file) that might be related to your issue.